# Main Domain and sub domain are pointing to same directory

Tags: apache, symfony, ubuntu, devops, vps

First of all, I am quite new to VPS and trying to point my new domain to my VPS server and and yes, DevOps newbie.
I just brought a domain name called htunhtunhtet.me from Godaddy and I wanted to have a subdomain, which is fandc.htunhtunhtet.me. The attached file is the configuration file for my web application under sites-available.

[image]

And below is my GoDaddy setting

[image]

what I am trying to achieve is when I visit fandc.htunhtunhtet.me, I wanted to show my web application and when I visit htunhtunhtet.me. I wanted to show a different application. How can I achieve this? Currently whenever I go htunhtunhtet.me.  or fandc.htunhtunhtet.me, it is showing the same web application.

NOTE: I am using LAMP stack and ubuntu and symfony

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#sub-domain-routing

Comment: This is not the answer to this question thought.